# Mocking a Rest Service .exectute(request) method and return a response

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing

I am trying to unit-test a rest client service, in which I have to mock a httpClient.execute(postRequest) method and return a HttpResponse. I have the respose string. Is there any way creating a Httpresposne with that string?

Answer (score 0):

You can create [StringEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html) and then set it to `HttpResponse`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Powermock` and mock both the execute method and the `HttpResponse`